# putting php variables into SOAP request array

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to put some PHP variables into an array but I cannot get it to work without getting errors.

Original Code:

```
  "DeclaredValue"=>0,
  "Accessorials"=>array("OriginLiftgate"),
  "OverDimensionPcs"=>0
```

What I was trying:

```
  $RLPickupLiftgate = 'OriginPickup';

  "DeclaredValue"=>0,
  "Accessorials"=>array($RLPickupLiftgate),
  "OverDimensionPcs"=>0
```

Sometimes the variable $RLPickupLiftgate will be empty and the error is triggered. I tried putting some logic into this section of the array but its not working.

As I side note I do understand that the variable does not contain quotes as the original code does.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
if (!isset($RLPickupLiftgate) && empty($RLPickupLiftgate)) {
    $RLPickupLiftgate = 'OriginPickup';
}
```